# Flutter PDFX PdfRendererException

Tags: android, flutter, pdf, render

I'm new to Flutter. I'm trying to open a pdf loaded in assets. I tried with open_file, but clicking on the button doesn't open anything and it doesn't show any errors.
Now I tried with pdfx and this is the error I get. I've searched a lot on the internet, but haven't found any solutions. please does anyone know how to fix this?

Here is my code:

```
final pdfPinchController = PdfControllerPinch(
  document: PdfDocument.openAsset('assets/pdf/ECO_RA.pdf'),
    //final document = await PdfDocument.openAsset('assets/sample.pdf')
);
```

```
            ElevatedButton(
                style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                  backgroundColor: Colors.green, // Background color
                ),
                onPressed: (){
                  try{
                     PdfViewPinch(
                       controller: pdfPinchController,
                    );
                    print('open');
                  }catch(e){
                  print(e.toString());
                  }

                  },
                child: const Text('Scarica PDF',
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16, color: Colors.white),
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center)
            )),
```

```
E/flutter (26595): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(PdfRendererException, io.scer.pdfx.PdfRendererException: File not found, Cause: null, Stacktrace: io.scer.pdfx.PdfRendererException: File not found
E/flutter (26595):  at io.scer.pdfx.Messages.openDocumentAsset(Messages.kt:96)
E/flutter (26595):  at dev.flutter.pigeon.Pigeon$PdfxApi$-CC.lambda$setup$2(Pigeon.java:1219)
E/flutter (26595):  at dev.flutter.pigeon.Pigeon$PdfxApi$$ExternalSyntheticLambda4.onMessage(Unknown Source:2)
E/flutter (26595):  at io.flutter.plugin.common.BasicMessageChannel$IncomingMessageHandler.onMessage(BasicMessageChannel.java:217)
E/flutter (26595):  at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.invokeHandler(DartMessenger.java:295)
E/flutter (26595):  at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.lambda$dispatchMessageToQueue$0$io-flutter-embedding-engine-dart-DartMessenger(DartMessenger.java:322)
E/flutter (26595):  at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.run(Unknown Source:12)
E/flutter (26595):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
E/flutter (26595):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/flutter (26595):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:236)
E/flutter (26595):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8069)
E/flutter (26595):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/flutter (26595):  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:620)
E/flutter (26595):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1011)
E/flutter (26595): , null)
E/flutter (26595): #0      PdfxApi.openDocumentAsset (package:pdfx/src/renderer/io/pigeon.dart:598:7)
E/flutter (26595): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (26595): #1      PdfxPlatformPigeon.openAsset (package:pdfx/src/renderer/io/platform_pigeon.dart:41:9)
E/flutter (26595): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (26595):
```

I think I've tried everything, but I just can't fix it

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible scenarios to your problem:

1. Missing file. Make sure to add your asset name to the `pubsec.yaml` file under the `assets` section.
2. Async problem. The file you are trying to display has not been found yet. I had the same problem, while I was trying to open file on the start of the activity, and the solution I found was this:

I have added this code in the `didChangeDependencies` override:

```
setState(() {
     _pdfController = PdfController(
         document: PdfDocument.openAsset("your_source_here:"),
     );
 });
```

You may paste this code to the `onPressed` function.

To use this variant, you should remove `final` from the pdfController declaration, and use `var` instead.

Hope this helps.